# How to find DLLs loaded by a web application?

Tags: .net, asp.net, debugging, iis

is there a way in .NET to clearly see what are the DLLs that a process (in this case an IIS process) has loaded to run an application?

It is a general question out of curiosity (I can't recall any way to inspect a .NET process and find out what DLLs it is using) and also because I have both Oracle DLLs (x86 and x64) running and I would like to make sure which is one is being used my app for debugging purposes.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried this and it worked perfectly:

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies.aspx):

> **Summary:**   Gets the assemblies that have been loaded into the
>   execution context of this application domain.

if you run this code in your ASP.NET application the output will contain:

- GAC assemblies like mscorlib, System.Web, etc.
- Custom assemblies referenced in your app
- Dynamic DLLs built for your pages and user controls, global.ascx, etc... (usually having log weird names)

Comment: That did the job. Lazy me not searching better before :P